# Django: filtering on `DecimalField` doesn't work well?

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my `model`:

```
class Tick(BaseModel):
    .
    .
    trade_coin_volume = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=8,
    )
    trade_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=8,
    )
    .
    .
```

I print out `trade_coin_volume` of all `Tick` objects:

```
In [9]: for tick in Tick.objects.all():
   ...:     print(tick.trade_coin_volume)
   ...:
0.02120853
0.05000000
0.26628998
0.19354556
0.32299392
0.72599405
0.05955935
0.05354201
0.00767441
0.05101970
0.20967645
0.10000001
0.00500000
0.00899999
0.15274410
0.32104315
0.00300000
0.22695384
0.05000000
0.13894616
0.00631414
0.07967759
0.28592241
0.23765636
0.05777923
0.08883787
0.05000000
0.14535185
```

As you can see above, there are some `0.05000000` values.

But when I filter `Tick` objects based on this field,

```
In [11]: Tick.objects.filter(trade_coin_volume=0.05)
Out[11]: <QuerySet []>

In [12]: Tick.objects.filter(trade_coin_volume=0.05000000)
Out[12]: <QuerySet []>
```

It doesn't show anything!

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django DecimalField represented in Python by [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) instance. Try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Tick.objects.filter(trade_coin_volume=Decimal('0.05'))
```

Comment: Even when storing data, do I have to wrap float number with `Decimal`?

Comment: @user3595632 during saving convertion will be performed automatically.